# Wireless keeps disconnecting on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit installed on dual boot Macbook pro

Tags: 14.04, networking, broadcom, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Macbook pro. Wireless stops working in between. My Macbook pro has "Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n" network controller. I have tried many methods suggested in the forum. 
Purged `bcmwl-kernel-source` and installed `firmware-43-installer`. I can see with `ethtool -i wlan0` that I am using b43 driver.
Power management mode is off. I have also done:

```
sudo iw wlan0 set power_save off
```

Still Wireless stops working in between. I have attached link for the output from wireless info script.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/16007042/

Comment: From what you briefly explained you seem to have made everything right. You could try a more recent kernel (`sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial` and reboot) but this issue may be due to something outside of your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. In the replies they had mentioned version 3.18 of the kernel. I think I have 3.19 kernel running. The output of uname -a on my system is "Linux MacBookPro 3.19.0-58-generic #64~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 19:05:43 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux". Do you think I should still upgrade the kernel? Thanks once again.

Comment: Yes. Your kernel version is included in the wireless diagnostics.

Comment: Thanks. I tried new kernel.  The problem persists. It does seem like problem with Ubuntu wireless because at that time I can connect to internet from other machine. So, it is not problem with the router.  Also, when I am not able to connect on Ubuntu, I tried ping to my router 192.168.1.1. It replies "destination host unreachable" at that time. Which means some issue with my wireless connection only. I would appreciate any other suggestions. I had noticed another answer in forum about some "disable n" or something like that. I am not sure about that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wanted to mention wireless stops working for sometime and then comes back again automatically. This keeps happening. This was the same pattern with earlier kernel version also.